# Difference between internal and moduleprivate in Swift

Tags: swift, internal, swift3, access-specifier

I am not able to understand what is the difference between these two keywords in swift3?

If anyone has a link to a good article about this, please share.

Comment: `moduleprivate`, it appears, was under discussion but ultimately rejected.  Please form your question in relation to the official spec, which has been accepted here as SE-0025 (SE means Swift Evolution): https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0025-scoped-access-level.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference conceptually; `moduleprivate` was just a possible alternate name for the same access level that didn't get accepted during discussions about access control modifier naming.

https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160328/013854.html

The `internal` modifier is the only one of the two that actually exists in the Swift language, but the two names represent the same behavior.

Comment: Good find. But I wouldn't call that "no difference": "internal" is a Swift keyword and "moduleprivate" isn't.